# From pandas to dictionary so that the value in column one will be the key and the corresponding values in column two will all be in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a very big pandas DataFrame as the following:

```
        t   gid
0   2010.0  67290
1   2020.0  92780
2   2040.0  92780
3   2060.0  92780
4   2090.0  92780
5   2110.0  92780
6   2140.0  92780
7   2190.0  92780
8   2010.0  69110
9   2010.0  78420
10  2020.0  78420
11  2020.0  78420
12  2030.0  78420
13  2040.0  78420
```

and I want to translate it to a dictionary such that I get:

gid_to_t[gid] == list of all t's,

for example -  gid_to_t[92778] == [2020,2040,2060,2090,2110...]

I know I can do the following:

```
gid_to_t = {}
for i,gid in enumerate(list(sps.gid)):
    gid_to_t[gid] = list(sps[sps.gid==gid].t)
```

but it takes too long, and I will be happy to find a faster way.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I've checked the methods suggested in the comments, this is the data:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1d3zUkc543hm8CZ_ZyzAzdbmQUE_G55bU

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_pickle('stack.pkl')

%timeit -n 2 df1.groupby('gid')['t'].apply(list).to_dict()
2 loops, best of 3: 4.76 s per loop
%timeit -n 2 df1.groupby('gid')['t'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_dict()
2 loops, best of 3: 4.21 s per loop
%timeit -n 2 df1.groupby('gid', sort=False)['t'].apply(list).to_dict()
2 loops, best of 3: 4.84 s per loop
%timeit -n 2 {name: group.tolist() for name, group in df1.groupby('gid')['t']}
2 loops, best of 3: 4 s per loop
%timeit -n 2 {name: group.tolist() for name, group in df1.groupby('gid', sort=False)['t']}
2 loops, best of 3: 3.96 s per loop
%timeit -n 2 {name: group['t'].tolist() for name, group in df1.groupby('gid', sort=False)}
2 loops, best of 3: 7.16 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more answer that doesn't use apply.

```
d = {name: group.tolist() for name, group in df.groupby('gid')['t']}

{67290: [2010.0],
 69110: [2010.0],
 78420: [2010.0, 2020.0, 2020.0, 2030.0, 2040.0],
 92780: [2020.0, 2040.0, 2060.0, 2090.0, 2110.0, 2140.0, 2190.0]}
```

Comment: what's bad in apply?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply anything is wrong with using `apply`. This is just an alternative method that showcases how a groupby object is iterable which you can then use to create a dictionary through a comprehension.

Comment: It is also faster :)

Comment: @Oren - Can you test last paragraph of my answer with your real data?

Comment: @Oren - for apply not help `sort=False`, but for dict comprehension? `%timeit -n 2 {name: group.tolist() for name, group in df1.groupby('gid', sort=False)['t']}` or  `%timeit -n 2 {name: group['t'].tolist() for name, group in df1.groupby('gid', sort=False)}` ?

Comment: @jezrael I've tried all methods.. I uploaded the data, feel free to try whatever you like. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try create `dictionary` by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) from `Series` of `list`s created by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
#if necessary convert column to int
df.t = df.t.astype(int)
d = df.groupby('gid')['t'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (d)
{92780: [2020, 2040, 2060, 2090, 2110, 2140, 2190], 
 67290: [2010], 
 78420: [2010, 2020, 2020, 2030, 2040], 
 69110: [2010]}

print (d[78420])
[2010, 2020, 2020, 2030, 2040]
```

If performance is important add `sort=False` parameter to `groupby`:

```
d = df.groupby('gid', sort=False)['t'].apply(list).to_dict()
d = {name: group.tolist() for name, group in df.groupby('gid', sort=False)['t']}
d = {name: group['t'].tolist() for name, group in df.groupby('gid', sort=False)}
```

Comment: I will test which method is faster and will select it. Thanks.

Comment: sure, also fastest is `d = df.groupby('gid')['t'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).to_dict()`